# GitHub API: how efficiently get the total count of Issues per repository?

Tags: github, curl, github-pages, github-api

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{org}/{repo}/issues
```

What query can allow us to find total count of issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Rest API, you can use the search api:

```
GET https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:bertrandmartel/tableau-scraping%20is:issue
```

https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:bertrandmartel/tableau-scraping%20is:issue

Output

```json
{
  "total_count": 8,
  ....
}
```

---

You can also use [Github graphql API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql) using the following request :

```json
{
  repository(owner: "mui-org", name: "material-ui") {
    issues {
      totalCount
    }
  }
}
```

[try this in the explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer)

With curl:

```sh
curl -H "Authorization: token YOUR_TOKEN" \
     -H  "Content-Type:application/json" \
     -d '{ 
          "query": "{ repository(owner: \"mui-org\", name: \"material-ui\") { issues { totalCount } } }"
      }' https://api.github.com/graphql
```

Sample output:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "issues": {
        "totalCount": 12760
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what i'm looking for, please let me know if i can get total_count using .Get and quarry params.

Ref:
https://api.github.com/repos/{org}/{repo}/issues